# Regex to find string match in another string with any whitespace

Tags: javascript, c#, string

I would like to find string matches within another string the following way:

Have a fix string like: "BRB"

Have different - test - sentences like:

- "What be right b means?" does not match
- "What b r b means?" match
- "What BR b means?" match
- "What BR-b means?" match
- "what brb means?" match

etc.

So I try to match the fix string within another string where possible whitespace characters (i.e. spaces) occures in between the characters.

How would it be possible to compose the regexp?

I am a newbie regex user so could not figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regex pattern, in case insensitive mode:

```
\b(?i)b[ -]?r[ -]?b\b
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

- `\b` a word boundary
- `(?i)` in case insensitive mode
- `b` the first letter `b`
- `[ -]` optional space or hyphen separator
- `r` the second letter `r`
- `[ -]` optionap space or hyphen separator
- `b` third letter `b`
- `\b` word boundary

Answer (score 0):

For c# you can use this

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       string pattern = @"b( |-)?r( |-)?b";
       string input = @"what brb means?";
       RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
    
       foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
       }
   }
}
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mzpKTq/1)